# Java look up something on Google

Tags: java

I have a simple problem with Java. I cannot figure out how to write a program to look up input on Google, like if the user prompts a text, or picture, the program will search it on Google and "spit out" the first result. If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful. It is connected to an extracurricular project for Internet control in schools (so that kids don't google bad things). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start by looking at the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).